# MVC routes serve in the index (index.php/path) and not normally (site/path)

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller, vps

I uploaded an MVC application (Model view controller) to a vps, the detail is the routing, by default the index.php is in a folder "public" and the path "/" if it shows well, but the later paths as "/portfolio" are not shown directly, to access them I have to put "index.php/portfolio" which is not desired, if you want to see it personally the site is this: [www.miatodesign.com](http://www.miatodesign.com).

There it loads the main page but not the others, to access put "miatodesign.com/index.php/portfolio" and there it shows them. I use php in the apache server and composer.

My routes are:

```
$router->get('/', [PublicController::class, 'viewIndex']);
$router->get('/portfolio', [PublicController::class, 'viewPortfolio']);
$router->get('/services', [PublicController::class, 'viewServices']);
$router->get('/contact', [PublicController::class, 'viewContact']);
```

I tried to configure an .htaccess file and it didn't work, also to change the paths directly, for example "../portfolio" and it didn't work either.

Comment: What MVC framework are you using? Laravel? How does your .htaccess look like?

Answer (score 0):

Its a common issue with your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This rules ensures that all requests that are not for a specific file (-f) or directory (-d) are rerouted through index.php (otherwise your web resources will not load properly), allowing your MVC application to handle the routing internally without requiring index.php in the URL.